# Get element position in ZStack

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Cheers everyone,

For the past couple of days I have been trying to find a way, to identify elements within a ZStack.

File structure

```
ZStack {
  foreach { element in
     SubView(element)
  }
}
```

I always have 3 elements stacked on top of each other & really want to get the top most element, to be able to edit some properties.

Any solution to this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `elements.enumerated()`

Comment: @Cy-4AH, thanks a lot. Sadly this doesn't apply. I didn't make clear, that the "element" in the foreach is actually a subview, which gets the foreach el as param. According to Xcode it's not possible to SubView(el: element).enumerated()

Comment: That code is not syntactically correct by any means. If you mean to use `ForEach`, the initializer for that is completely different. Please repost correct code and we should be able to help you.

Comment: @Cy-4AH sorry, yeah, the code is just a visualization, not the real deal. But thanks for the indirect tipp on sharing proper code examples.
In my case, I was able to resolve it as seen below. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this specific case

Background:
The View that is being loaded in the loop is in an array, that I previously created. The array also contain an ID.

What I did now was to find out the max ID, reverse loop through my array while passing the current ID and the current max ID to the new view, where I can handle the data accordingly.
So if the max ID == currentElement ID, I can apply my changes, thus also getting the topmost card.